# Cannot visualse project with Mac Sierra

Tags: qgis, mac, qgs

I recently updated my Mac to Sierra OS. In the past, I had use QGIS without any problem with my previous OS version (Lion). Since I installed Sierra, I can open shapes, visualise maps and export images, and also save my project. However, if I want to re-open the project, I see nothing on the display, even though I see the project shapes to the left. So I reinstalled QGIS from king chaos, I now have 2.16 version. Still the same. I can work with QGIS, save project, but when I re-open the project, the display is empty.

Does anybody know what is happening and how to fix the problem?